# Split text according to font and width

Tags: java

I need to split text according to font and width.

for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   String text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;"
   int width = 50;
   int fontSize = 20;
   Font fontArial = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
   String[] textA = getSplittedText(text, fontArial, width); //return splitted text
}
```

> methods:

```
public static String[] getSplittedText(String text, Font font, int width) {
   JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
   label.setFont(font);
   int textLength = label.getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth(text);
   return getTextArrayByLength(label, textLength, width);
}

public static String[] getTextArrayByLength(Jlabel label, int textLength, int width){
   //What I need
}
```

Comment: Why not just let the LayoutManager deal with the width?

Comment: @NomadMaker What do you mean? I only need a string index that is larger than the width.